# Distrubuting an app on Play Store via URL

Tags: android

I have an app that I would only like certain people to access. I need to be able to distribute the app via Play Store because the receivers don't want to have to download from an external source. I have seen it done before that an app is distributed via URL using the beta channel, in which it was a closed beta, but anyone with a link could join the test. I know that I can use Google+ or Google Groups, but the end users will not want to join such services. We don't have G Suite, the end users are not part of the organisation.

Here's my situation:

- Client requests an app for an ongoing event
- Client doesn't want people from outside the event to access the app
- My idea is to distribute the app via the Play Store, but only people who have a link to the app can download it

If all else fails I am considering just using a password which will be distributed to the users, but this will mean that the app can be viewed on the Play Store by people not within the event.

I hope I have provided enough information, I get if this sounds confusing so please ask for more detail if necessary.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to restrict the app to specific set of users. Best what can you do is as follows.

1. Restrict your app with some credentials
2. Upload the app in play store with some weird name and description
   which rarely anybody will relate to
3. Restrict the country in play store
4. Create a short url for your play store link and distribute to your users